# How to identify the browser and redirect the user if that's not the correct browser?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a website to do for university and the teacher wants us to include code that checks what browser the user is using and if the browser isn't Firefox, they should be redirected elsewhere.

I have this so far:

```
function fnBrowserDetect(){                            
  let userAgent = navigator.userAgent;          
  let browserName;                    
  if(userAgent.match(/chrome|chromium|crios/i)){              
    browserName = "chrome";            
  }else if(userAgent.match(/firefox|fxios/i)){              
    browserName = "firefox";            
  }  else if(userAgent.match(/safari/i)){
    browserName = "safari";            
  }else if(userAgent.match(/opr\//i)){              
    browserName = "opera";            
  } else if(userAgent.match(/edg/i)){              
    browserName = "edge";            
  }else{              
    browserName="No browser detection";            
  }                     
document.querySelector("h1").innerText="You are using "+ browserName +" browser";            
}

function redirect(){
  if(browserName != "firefox"){
    window.location.replace("www.google.com");
  } else {
    window.location.href = "../index.php";
  }
}
```

Can someone help me out and let me know how can I do this correctly?

Comment: you have to call the function, then return a value, browserName is not in scope

Comment: As an aside, its pointless to try and force a particular browser effectively. User agent spoofing is trivial. What is your actual goal by blocking other browsers?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of `fnBrowserDetect`, you can return `browserName` so you can use it in your other function.

Also make sure to include the protocol (`https://`) in your redirect URL.

```js
function fnBrowserDetect(){                            
  let userAgent = navigator.userAgent;          
  let browserName;                    
  if(userAgent.match(/chrome|chromium|crios/i)){              
    browserName = "chrome";            
  }else if(userAgent.match(/firefox|fxios/i)){              
    browserName = "firefox";            
  }  else if(userAgent.match(/safari/i)){
    browserName = "safari";            
  }else if(userAgent.match(/opr\//i)){              
    browserName = "opera";            
  } else if(userAgent.match(/edg/i)){              
    browserName = "edge";            
  }else{              
    browserName="No browser detection";            
  }                     
  document.querySelector("h1").innerText="You are using "+ browserName +" browser";         
  return browserName;
}

function redirect(){
  if(fnBrowserDetect() != "firefox"){
    window.location.replace("https://www.google.com");
  } else {
    window.location.href = "../index.php";
  }
}
```