# How to fix my script to merge my two functions OR call them in specific order?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, browser, detect

I'm trying to use a script into a HTML (based on the solution suggested by "skara9" in [this post](https://https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70477346/how-to-identify-the-browser-and-redirect-the-user-if-thats-not-the-correct-brow) and try to adapt it for my needs, but can't find how to do it, it doesn't work.

The basic has 2 functions:

- the 1st one:
  `function fnBrowserDetect()`
- and the 2nd function under the 1st one :
  `function redirect()`

But when I tried to execute it, only the 1st function worked. And I didn't found out how to call the 2 functions, so I decided to try to merge them. But it doesn't work either.
What am I doing wrong?

So here is my code now:

```
<body onload="fnBrowserDetect()">
<script>
    function fnBrowserDetect(){                            
        let userAgent = navigator.userAgent;          
        let browserName;                    
          if(userAgent.match(/chrome|chromium|brave|crios/i)){              
        browserName = "chrome";            
          }else if(userAgent.match(/firefox|fxios/i)){              
        browserName = "firefox";                   
          }else if(userAgent.match(/opr\//i)){              
        browserName = "opera";            
          } else if(userAgent.match(/edg/i)){              
        browserName = "edge";            
          }else{              
        browserName="No browser detection";            
        }                           
        return browserName;
        if(browserName = "chrome"){
        window.location.replace("https//specific-just-working.better-google-chrome-page/");
         } else if(browserName = "firefox"){
        window.location.replace("https://specific-just-working.better-firefox-page/");
         } else if(browserName = "edge"){
        window.location.replace("https://specific-just-working.better-edge-microsoft-page/");
         } else if(browserName = "opera"){
        window.location.replace("https://specific-just-working.better-opera-page/");
         }
    }
</script>
</body>
```

It would be too long to explain why I have to do that (the redirected links are only here as distinctive examples) but the thing is I am looking for a simple way to DETECT the browser used by the person and REDIRECT him to the correct place according the browser that person is using.

**HERE IS WHAT I ALREADY TRIED: **

First I tried to execute the script as it was as the beginning and for this, and looked for a way to call multiple functions. According some posts I read here, I read it is possible to do that with eitheir `window.onload = function()` OR `window.addEventListener('load', ...)` .
But (i'm sorry) it wasn't explained clearly enough for me...

So after that, I decided to try to merge my 2 functions based on a logic but it still doesn't work.
I changed this part in particular:

**REMOVED:**

```
browserName="No browser detection";            
  }                     
  document.querySelector("h1").innerText="You are using "+ browserName +" browser";         
  return browserName;
}

function redirect(){
  if(fnBrowserDetect() != "firefox"){
    window.location.replace("https://www.google.com");
```

**REPLACED BY:**

```
browserName="No browser detection";            
    }                           
    return browserName;
    if(browserName = "chrome"){
    window.location.replace("https//google-chrome-website");
```

So I'm looking for someone to help me to correct it please.

**Hoverwise, if you think it's better to call 2 functions rather than merge my code like I did:**

Please specify me how and where to call the `window.onload = function()` instead of `<body onload="function()">` . Do I need to add a div or a script like :

```
<script>
window.onload = function();
</script>
```

And also tell me how to call my 2 functions in specific order (function1 then function2).

Maybe it's better to use an external script.js ?

Just tell me. Thank you.

(Please avoid to suggest me other similar post because I already passed many days on them but they weren't clear enough for me ; I'm still learning and need clear explanations. Thx)

Comment: You have an extra quote here: `""https//specific-just-working.better-google-chrome-page/"`

Comment: Nothing is executed after `return browserName`. So none of the `if (browserName = ...)` statements will be executed. Also, all those `=` should be `==`.

Comment: There are a lot of questions here. Please narrow it down to one problem at a time. If you have other problems, they should be separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of back and forth with what you removed and tried. So I just took the base functionality and cleaned it up.

First, your return stops everything from happening after that.

My answer returns two pieces of the data: The name of the browser and the GOTO URL.

Instead of if statements, I just a switch that works best for basic if/else statements like you had.

From there you can choose what you want to do with that data.

```js
function fnBrowserDetect() {
  let userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
  let returns = {
    "browser": "",
    "url": ""
  };
  if (userAgent.match(/chrome|chromium|brave|crios/i)) {
    returns["browser"] = "chrome";
  } else if (userAgent.match(/firefox|fxios/i)) {
    returns["browser"] = "firefox";
  } else if (userAgent.match(/opr\//i)) {
    returns["browser"] = "opera";
  } else if (userAgent.match(/edg/i)) {
    returns["browser"] = "edge";
  } else {
    returns["browser"] = "No browser detection";
  }

  switch (returns["browser"]) {
    case "chrome":
      returns["url"] = "https //specific-just-working.better-google-chrome-page/";
      break;
    case "firefox":
      returns["url"] = "https://specific-just-working.better-firefox-page/";
      break;
    case "edge":
      returns["url"] = "https://specific-just-working.better-edge-microsoft-page/";
      break;
    case "opera":
      returns["url"] = "https://specific-just-working.better-opera-page/";
      break;
    default:
      returns["url"] = "https://google.com/";
      break;
  }

  return returns;
}

let browser = fnBrowserDetect();

document.querySelector("#browser").innerText = browser.browser;
document.querySelector("#url").innerText = browser.url;

//location.href = browser.url;
```

```html
<div id="browser"></div>
<div id="url"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Barman, i removed the extra "" (but there were only here in my example, not in my code). 
@imvain2 Thank you for having wrote the full code for me.  It works but only for display the text (example: firefox  https://specific-just-working.better-firefox-page/) ; of course, it's because of the "innerText" at the end of the code. But I can't redirect. 
I tried with your div id but probably I'm not using them correctly. I'm sorry, you will think I'm really dumb.

Comment: @Noob.Geek.Guy74 to redirect just remove the // before **location.href = browser.url;**